# Google Oauth multiple device

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm currently making an Google Drive App. The application already works well, now it can list Google Drive Files inside native view. The problem I found is when I use same account to oauth on 2 different device (one run in 2.3 and the other in 4.0), the gingerbread will get error like this:

> 08-27 15:29:22.659: W/System.err(4425): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

The app works well on both device if I use 2 different account. My question: is it possible to use single account(oauth account) on multiple device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Your error is almost certainly a problem in your app/environment.

A 401 error simply means you need a fresh accesstoken. This happens routinely (typically every hour) so your app needs to catch this error and refresh the token.

Comment: yeah i'm invalidate the wrong account, so the access token is not replaced.. now it fixed thanks for your answer..